# Create table of records from subsets of a dataframe in python using datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Be the following pandas DataFrame in Python:

| ID | date | direction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 10:00:01 | IN |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 11:00:01 | IN |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 11:10:01 | OUT |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 12:00:03 | IN |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 14:32:01 | OUT |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 10:32:01 | OUT |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 11:32:01 | IN |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 14:32:01 | OUT |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 08:00:01 | OUT |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 08:02:01 | IN |

I need to get the check-in and check-out for each group by ID. Considering that an `entry_date` is registered by direction = IN and an `exit_date` by direction = OUT. The idea is to create the record as follows:

| ID | entry_date | exit_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 10:00:01 | 2022-01-03 11:10:01 |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 12:00:03 | 2022-01-03 14:32:01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 11:32:01 | 2022-01-04 14:32:01 |

They are only recorded if a row with IN appears first and closes the record with a row with OUT as value for direction column (there may be more rows in between with a value of direction IN, as can be seen in the example).

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but here's an attempt.

After sorting along the `date` column (`date` should be `datetime`): Group on `ID` and then eliminate in three steps all rows that don't fit into the required pattern: 1. eliminate `OUT`-blocks at the beginning of every group. 2. reduce consecutive blocks of `IN`/`OUT`s in each group to the first one. 3. Remove the the last row of the group if it is an `IN`-row. The rest is essentially splitting the resulting dataframe in 2 interlaced parts and concatenating them next to another.

```
def connect(df):
    df = df[df["direction"].cummax()]
    df = df[df["direction"].diff().fillna(True)]
    if df.shape[0] % 2:
        df = df.iloc[:-1]
    return df

result = (
    df
    .assign(direction=df["direction"].replace({"IN": True, "OUT": False}))
    .sort_values(["ID", "date"])
    .groupby("ID").apply(connect)
    .drop(columns="direction")
    .droplevel(-1, axis=0)
)
result = pd.concat(
    [result.iloc[0::2], result[["date"]].iloc[1::2]], axis=1
).reset_index(drop=True)
result.columns = ["ID", "entry_date", "exit_date"]
```

Result:

```
   ID          entry_date           exit_date
0   0 2022-01-03 10:00:01 2022-01-03 11:10:01
1   0 2022-01-03 12:00:03 2022-01-03 14:32:01
2   1 2022-01-04 11:32:01 2022-01-04 14:32:01
```

---

Another solution would be to group by `ID`, and then, in each group, split the `directions` in 2 stacks, the `ins` and `outs`, and run through them to gather the connections:

```
def connect(df):
    mask = df["direction"].eq("IN")
    ins = list(reversed(df.loc[mask, "date"].values))
    outs = list(reversed(df.loc[~mask, "date"].values))
    connects = []
    if ins:
        dt_out = ins[-1] + pd.Timedelta(days=-1)
    while ins and outs:
        dt_in = None
        while ins:
            dt = ins.pop()
            if dt > dt_out:
                dt_in = dt
                break
        while dt_in and outs:
            dt_out = outs.pop()
            if dt_in < dt_out:
                connects.append([dt_in, dt_out])
                break
    return pd.DataFrame(
        connects, columns=["entry_date", "exit_date"]
    )

result = (
    df.sort_values(["ID", "date"]).groupby("ID").apply(connect)
      .droplevel(1, axis=0).reset_index()
)
```

Comment: It's just the performance I was looking for. I am using the second method as the first one gives me an error on the next line: ```df.pivot_table(index=pd.Index([n // 2 for n in range(df.shape[0])]),columns="direction", values="date")```

Comment: Using the second method I would like the resulting DataFrame to have its own column for the value of "ID", with your solution I get "ID" as index, how could I change this?

Comment: The error for the first method is as follows:```raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")```, I mention it because maybe the first method is more efficient and faster and you can help me to understand what happens with this error.

Comment: @Carola See the edit: reseting the index should work.

Comment: @Carola Do you get the error already for the sample here, or is there some structure that the sample doesn't show?

Comment: There are other columns in the original, but they should not interfere with the calculation of the ones I have shown here.

Comment: @Carola I have replaced method 1 with a pivot-less version. Maybe that works?